# PhoneGap and zeroconf plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, zeroconf

I am trying to develop PhoneGap application which uses zeroconf plugin for cordova. I Have followed intructions from:

cordova-plugin-zeroconf

My code looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function onDeviceReady() {
        document.getElementById("zeroconf2").innerHTML = "Looking for Domo Device...";
        var ZeroConf = cordova.plugins.zeroconf;
        console.log(ZeroConf);
        ZeroConf.watch('_mpd._tcp.', function(resp){
            document.getElementById("zeroconf2").innerHTML = resp.service;
            console.log("Found something");
        });
    }
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    onLoad();
  </script>
```

I have added plugin to config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-zeroconf" source="npm"/>
```

When I am previewing my app on device. I am not able to receive any information regarding `_mpd._tcp` devices in my network.
In same time  I am able to see them using zeronf browser, so I know that zeroconf is working in my lan.

BR Marcin

Comment: I know this was a long time ago. Did you get your problem solved?